# write and force site to use custome Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, web, browser

a friend of mine has a website and doesn't have access to it's files (sort of classified somthing like that ) , the problem is when a user log in it just takes him 5 minutes and logged of because Cookies expiration is 5 minutes , he asked me to make a land page where the visitors can click on a button that leads them to the site , but also put a custom Cookie file in the browser with expiration time 5 days or a week or a long time the 5 minutes :) , i really don't know how , can you help me please !

Answer (score 0):

A cookie by default is deleted when the user closes the browser. To set a time of expiration you can add a parameter `expires` in the cookie like this:

```
var d = Date.UTC(2017,10,25);
```

And then inside your cookie you set the expiry date to that UTC date

```
document.cookie = "expires =" + d;
```

You can't force a cookie to be persistant, the user can clear his browser when ever he wants.

Comment: sorry i am late to respond :( and thank you for your respond :) ,
i know that sir but if i made the same cookie their site has with this expiration date , will the browser still using my cookie or thiers ?

thanks advanced :)